# Real-Time Multi-Object Tracking with Learning

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, kalman-filter, hsv, video-tracking

My Goal is to have real-time MultiTracker with Learning.
I used Kalman filter to track an object but i found errors in the estimation while tracking. 
The object was not been tracked continuously. I want to implement some learning mechanism along with Tracking.
 One way i thought of doing this is,
1) calculate the average HSV of a particular roi then store that HSV value in a vector(`Scalar` or `Vec3b`)
2) Compare the new HSV value (average from some ROI) with all previous HSV values present in vector collection. 
3)If the new HSV value did not match with the *HSV values in vector* then track this as a new separate object.
4) else if the new roi matched *HSV values in vector*, then it is said to be the same object present in the roi. continue tracking old object. 
5) Have some regular time based checking to remove old *HSV values in vector*.

I tried KCF, MIL e.t.c they are not realtime. can you recommend any realtime learning mecahnism or ways to improve above proposed one.